# Loop through list and append in R

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and I may be missing some info, but I cannot wrap my head around this behavior:

```
neighbors<-function(topo,usr){
  n = NULL
  for (i in 1:length(topo[,1])){
    if (topo[i,1] == usr){
      n <- append(n,topo[i,2])
    }
  }
return(n)
}
```

Where `topo` has the following structure:

```
 2l59mm6jc8pae32vilsr99ljp0 40iml67hpjsr8o1oo7f4oin706
 3359mm6jc8pae32vilsr99ljp0 411iml67hpjsr8o1oo7f4oin706
 ...
```

What I would like to do is loop through the first column and see the matches with `usr` from the first column and add the content of the second column to `n`, that I return.

What happens is I get some numbers in the output: `19` and `16`. If I try to debug it I was getting the following answer:

```
   [1] vi4govpcqjnf6imquadf9ae4f0
   20 Levels: 2l59mm6jc8pae32vilsr99ljp0 40iml67hpjsr8o1oo7f4oin706 ... vvqp3im2g3r90ibv56817asfq7
   [1] 19
   [1] nb9b1vh6ocaqsmgp8dv1s22f61
   20 Levels: 2l59mm6jc8pae32vilsr99ljp0 40iml67hpjsr8o1oo7f4oin706 ... vvqp3im2g3r90ibv56817asfq7
   [1] 19 16
   [1] 19 16
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?  And I used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` because in your code you are potentially matching a factor against a character string

```
topo <- data.frame(a=c('2l59mm6jc8pae32vilsr99ljp0','40iml67hpjsr8o1oo7f4oin706'),
               b=c('3359mm6jc8pae32vilsr99ljp0','411iml67hpjsr8o1oo7f4oin706'), 
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

neighbors <- function(topo, usr){ 
    n = c()
    for (i in seq_along(usr)){
      if (topo[i,1] == usr[i])
         n[i] <- topo[i,2]
    }
    return( n )
}

<r> neighbors(topo=topo, usr='2l59mm6jc8pae32vilsr99ljp0')
[1] "3359mm6jc8pae32vilsr99ljp0"

<r> neighbors(topo=topo, usr=c('2l59mm6jc8pae32vilsr99ljp0','40iml67hpjsr8o1oo7f4oin706'))
[1] "3359mm6jc8pae32vilsr99ljp0"  "411iml67hpjsr8o1oo7f4oin706"
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was searching for, but the other answer is more elegant.

Comment: agreed the other is better, wasn't sure how complicated your set up was though, so tried to work within your loop framework :)

Comment: But the other answer omitted the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, and that way it doesn't work

Comment: fixed to work for vectors > 1, this may not be the most elegant solution i admit

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Actually that won't work either - note that when you're on `topo[3,1]` for example, the statement will ONLY check for equality with `usr[3]`, not the whole vector. If `topo[,1]` is longer than `usr`, it will start returning `NA`s.

Answer (score 5):

A better approach would be:

```
n = topo[,2][topo[,1] %in% usr]
```

Without seeing your data set I can't say for sure, but there's two potential problems I see in your code:

1) `topo` columns 1 and 2 are factors. You should convert them to character.

2) If `usr` has more than one element, `if(topo[i,1] == usr)` will not work as intended.

Comment: This returns exactly what my function was returning. The accepted answer solved the problem as I had to set the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` (you told me that I might need to convert it to characters, but not how)